# Verilog - re-using register value on always posedge

Tags: verilog

Consider the following code:

```
Module Test  (B, A, CLK)

Input A, CLK;
Output B;

Reg RA;

Always @(Posedge CLK)

Begin

RA=A;
B=RA;

End
EndModule
```

Would that work properly to move the input to the register and then to the output on every positive edge? Can it be created with circuits?

Comment: difficult to say. your current code will not compile due to incorrect capitalized keywords in any case. So, please invest a bit of effort to  format your code before asking the question and provide an example you want to implement, so that there is no need to guess what you really wanted to do.

Comment: Also if your intend to simulate or synthesize a flip-flop, you should use the nonblobking assignment operator `<=`. (Whether to do this for `RA` or for `B` or both depends on the intention of the question, which is unclear.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do...

- If you just want a single flip-flop, the simplest way is to declare `reg B;` then you can write `always @(posedge CLK) B <= A;`. There is no need for another signal.
- If (for some style reason) you want to separate the flip-flop from the output, you can wire them together with a continuous assignment `assign B = RA;`. The circuit would be the same.
- If you want two flip-flops (2-stage pipeline), your code is almost correct but remember to declare `reg B;` and use `<=` for *both* updates (they can be written in either order).
- If `RA` is some sort of temporary variable for describing your intentions to the tools, then Yes; you can write to it with `=` and use its value in the same process (do not try to access it from any other process). This is occasionally useful for e.g. accumulating things in loops, but here it would just be confusing and error-prone!

To synthesize real hardware you would typically also have a reset signal and would need to use it in the proper way for each flip-flop.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, what you've written (conceptually) will work. In terms of syntax, here's something that will compile and do what you're thinking. Note that I've declared your output `B` a register and used nonblocking assignments for the registers.

```
module Test (
    input  wire CLK,
    input  wire A,
    output reg  B
);

    reg RA;

    always @(posedge CLK) begin
        RA <= A;
        B  <= RA;
    end

endmodule
```